# contact form 7 wordpress - how to change border-color form when the mouse is on

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm currenlty using wordpress and I'm trying to change the color of the border when the mouse is on.

Here is my URL: http://www.firstcareconsultancy.co.uk/firstcare/about-us/

As you can see, it's working for every part of the form except the email area.
I looked on the css file but I didn't find any "border-color" tag or yellow hexadecimal value..

Does anyone can help me ? Thanks :)

Comment: To view css styles applied to any element on the page use chromes inspect element function https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/basics (or the equivelent in any other browser)

Comment: You sometimes need to use "toggle element state" for :hover or :focus styles etc.

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out?

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that adds the border

```
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus, 
textarea:focus, select:focus, 
#bottom input[type="text"]:focus, 
#bottom input[type="password"]:focus, 
#bottom textarea:focus, #bottom select:focus {
    border-color: #f9cc60;
}
```

You need to add this

```
input[type="email"]:focus
```

To target input type email

```
<input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: Hello @sarcoma why the border-color: #f9cc60 isn't present in the css file ? 
How is it possible ? Becase as we can see, there is a yellow color when the mouse is on...so it should be a border-color ..

Comment: You have several css files. It's in http://www.firstcareconsultancy.co.uk/wp-content/themes/kindness/css/fonts.php?ver=1.0.0